# Getting "unknown command" Exception calling the "minimize_window" method

Tags: python, python-2.7, selenium, selenium-webdriver

Example code:

```
from selenium import webdriver

browser = webdriver.Chrome() 
browser.minimize_window()
```

Returns the following exception:

```
  File "myScript.py", line 4, in <module>
    browser.minimize_window()
  File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\selenium\webdriver\remote\webdriver.py", line 738, in minimize_window
    self.execute(Command.MINIMIZE_WINDOW)
  File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\selenium\webdriver\remote\webdriver.py", line 312, in execute
    self.error_handler.check_response(response)
  File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\selenium\webdriver\remote\errorhandler.py", line 208, in check_response
    raise exception_class(value)
selenium.common.exceptions.WebDriverException: Message: unknown command: session/8252be05ea571a2c623450db8ba097c0/window/minimize
```

Adding the line

```
print dir(browser)
```

Shows that `minimize_window()` is a listed function of browser. So what gives? Is this functionality just not compatible with Chrome?

Python 2.7

Comment: Works fine with Chrome on Python 3.6

Comment: Just tried it with maximize_window() and oddly that works fine.

Comment: Also work fine on Python 2.7.12 with Chrome... Try to upgrade your chromedriver to up-to-date version

Comment: v2.41 works! I get a weird chrome policy error if I try to use v2.42 or v2.43.

Comment: 2.43 works fine for me... Maybe you should update Chrome browser also?

Answer (score 1):

This error message...

```
selenium.common.exceptions.WebDriverException: Message: unknown command: session/8252be05ea571a2c623450db8ba097c0/window/minimize
```

...implies that the call to **minimize_window()** function wasn't recoznized.

You spotted it correct. As now *WebDriver Specification* is a *W3C Recommendation* the function defination for *maximizing* the window was adjusted as per the *W3C Recommended Specification* as follows:

```
def maximize_window(self):
    """
    Maximizes the current window that webdriver is using
    """
    params = None
    command = Command.W3C_MAXIMIZE_WINDOW
    if not self.w3c:
        command = Command.MAXIMIZE_WINDOW
        params = {'windowHandle': 'current'}
    self.execute(command, params)
```

But, the function defination for *minimizing* the window is still pending to be *W3C* compliant within the *Python Client* as is still defined as:

```
def minimize_window(self):
    """
    Invokes the window manager-specific 'minimize' operation
    """
    self.execute(Command.MINIMIZE_WINDOW)
```

Hence you see the error:

```
unknown command: session/8252be05ea571a2c623450db8ba097c0/window/minimize
```

---

### Solution

As the default/common practice is to open the browser in **maximized** mode, while *Test Execution* is *In Progress* **minimizing** the browser would be against the best practices as [Selenium](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54459701/what-is-selenium-and-what-is-webdriver/54482491#54482491) may loose the focus over the *Browsing Context* and an exception may raise during the *Test Execution*. However, *Selenium's* [python](/questions/tagged/python) client does have a [minimize_window()](https://www.selenium.dev/selenium/docs/api/py/webdriver_remote/selenium.webdriver.remote.webdriver.html#selenium.webdriver.remote.webdriver.WebDriver.minimize_window) method which eventually pushes the *Chrome Browsing Context* effectively to the background.

Python:

```
from selenium import webdriver

options = webdriver.ChromeOptions()
options.add_argument("--start-maximized")
options.add_experimental_option("excludeSwitches", ["enable-automation"])
options.add_experimental_option('useAutomationExtension', False)
driver = webdriver.Chrome(chrome_options=options, executable_path=r'C:\Utility\BrowserDrivers\chromedriver.exe')
driver.get('https://www.google.co.in')
driver.minimize_window()
```

Java Solution:

```
driver.navigate().to("https://www.google.com/");
Point p = driver.manage().window().getPosition();
Dimension d = driver.manage().window().getSize();
driver.manage().window().setPosition(new Point((d.getHeight()-p.getX()), (d.getWidth()-p.getY())));
```

Comment: And how would you explain that `minimize_window` works in Python 3.6 with exactly the same method definition?

Answer (score -1):

Just tried to downgrade my `chromedriver` version to 2.25 and got...

> selenium.common.exceptions.WebDriverException: Message: unknown command: session/f35727d2129895c35b24deeb7090eb26/window/minimize

with the same code.

But if to use the last ([2.43](https://chromedriver.storage.googleapis.com/index.html?path=2.43/)) it work just fine

So just upgrade to up-to-date `chromedriver` version to be able to use `minimize_window` method